# how to display pdf in web browser using webapi mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

i wan to display pdf in browser i have done the part, but its not displaying pdf, its directly downloading pdf, i dont want like that i want to display pdf directly here is my code.

```
[Route("api/DiagnosticDetail/RetrieveFile/{id}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage RetrieveFile(int id)
        {
    DiagnosticDetailModel diagnosticDetailModel = GetFileList(id);
            byte[] img = diagnosticDetailModel.FileContent.ToArray();
            HttpResponseMessage result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(img);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

            return result;
        }
        private DiagnosticDetailModel GetFileList(int id)
        {
            var DetList = db.DiagnosticDetailModels.Where(p => p.InpatientCodeId == id).FirstOrDefault();
           return DetList;
        }
```

Comment: which pdf rendering library in your application are you using

Comment: this is largely at the discretion of the browser. Some browsers (e.g. Internet Explorer being a big example) don't natively support PDF and require an extra plugin to be installed (e.g. Adobe Reader), and also they may nor may not honour the "inline" disposition header. All you can do is provide a hint about how you'd like thing to happen, which you have done. After that it's down to how the browser is configured and what the user's preference is. At the end of the day, all you're doing is serving a file from a server. How it's handled at the other end is not up to you - it's not your computer